# Execute batch instructions sequentially

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I have a problem with my batch file (.bat). It has the following lines :

```
start /d "\\Pcaldatp01\myroute" App1.exe

start /d "\\Pcaldatp01\myroute" App2.exe

start /d "\\Pcaldatp01\myroute" App3.exe

start /d "\\Pcaldatp01\myroute" App1.xlsm
```

But all of them execute at the same time, I want each application to execute in sequence after the previous one ends.
How to do it?

Comment: add the `/WAIT` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
start "" /wait /d "\\Pcaldatp01\myroute" App1.exe
start "" /wait /d "\\Pcaldatp01\myroute" App2.exe
start "" /wait /d "\\Pcaldatp01\myroute" App3.exe
start "" /wait /d "\\Pcaldatp01\myroute" App1.xlsm
```